# Setting active-class to work across multiple independent v-lists in vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js

I'm unable to make navigation selections using active-classes to work properly across multiple independent navigation v-list items in Vue 3.

Here is a reference to the navigation setup:

V-List 1: Item 1 (can be active)

V-List 1: Item 2 (can be active)

.................................

V-List 2: Item 1 (cannot be active) - Used for on expanding sub items actions.

---->V-List 2: Sub-Item 1 (can be active)

End goal is to only have one item that can be active in an active state (and thus selected).

Example: If [V-List 1: Item 1] is active/selected then [V-List 1: Item 2] & [V-List 2: Sub-Item 1] cannot be selected.

Example 2: If [V-List 2: Sub-Item 1] is selected then [V-List 1: Item 1] & [V-List 1: Item 2] cannot be selected.

Right now it works but only intermittently for some reason, and I'm unsure why. When I select [V-List 1: Item 1] or [V-List 1: Item 2] they successfully select themselves as the only active navigation. However when I select [V-List 2: Sub-Item 1] it sometimes works where it de-selects everything other than itself as active and sometimes it leaves [V-List 1: Item 1] or [V-List 1: Item 2] as selected alongside itself being select.

```
<v-navigation-drawer v-model="leftNavigation" @click="drawer = false">
<div>
    <v-list nav active-class="activeNav">
        <v-list-item title="V-List 1: Item 1" value="Item1" :to="routeUsed"></v-list-item>
        <v-list-item title="V-List 1: Item 2" value="Item2"></v-list-item>
    </v-list>

    <div v-if="session.navOption == 'Something'">
        <Vlist2-Nav :menu="menuItems" />
    </div>
</div>

/*import component*/
import Vlist2-Nav from "@/components/ui/vlist2-Nav.vue";
const routeUsed = computed(() => "/sess/" + session?.value?.id + "/" + session?.value?.terms + "/Home";
```

vList2-Nav.vue file:

```
<template>
    <v-list nav active-class="activeNav">
        <v-list-group v-for="item in V-List2Obj.menu" :key="item.title" :id="getId(item.title)">
            <template>
                //V-List 2: Item 1
                <v-list-item:title="item.title"></v-list-item>
            </template>
            <template v-if="!close">
                //V-List 2: Item 2
                <v-list-item v-for="subItems in item.items" :key="subItems.title" :title="subItems.title" :to="New"></v-list-item>
            </template>
        </v-list-group>
    </v-list>
</template>
```

Adding more edits as I'm understanding the code more.

Here is the code of the router file:

```
const navigationPage = () => import("@/views/LeftNavigationView.vue");
const home = () => import("@/views/Terms/Home.vue");
const newTerm = () => import("@/views/Terms/Func/New.vue")

import { RouteRecordRaw } from "vuex";

const routes: Array<RouteRecordRaw> = [
{
    path: "Terms",
    redirect: (from) => "/sess/" + from.params.id + "/Terms/Home",
    component: navigationPage,
    children: [
        { path: "Home", component: home },
        { path: "New", component: newTerm },
    ],
},
]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is v-list? Vuetify? This needs to be explicitly stated

Comment: Yes Vuetify! Should've mentioned so.

Comment: It should be `to="/Terms/New"` instead of `:to="New"`, no colon, this is the problem I see. If the problem persists, please, provide a way to reproduce, this is something that needs to be debugged